# How to copy the content of one list to Clipboard?

Tags: python, list, clipboard

I want to copy the content of one List to Clipboard for next action, and I have used `win32Clipboard` module and use For Cycle to get each element, then `SetClipboardData`, but it seems does not work.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
import win32clipboard as winClip 

winClip.OpenClipboard()
winClip.EmptyClipboard()
for MATNR in errorMATNR:
    winClip.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_MAX, str(MATNR[0]))
winClip.CloseClipboard()
```

`errorMATNR` is the List, which stores the content.

Comment: I found that, module `pyperlip`also can only operate one line data every time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem here might be that you overwrite the contents of the clipboard in each iteration, and that results in having only one element of the list at the time on the clipboard (i assume this is what you mean by "does not seem to work")

You should first construct the list from `str(MATNR[0])` elements, ant then pass it to the `SetClipboardData` function, like this:

```
cliplist = []
for MATNR in errorMATNR:
    cliplist.append(str(MATNR[0])

winClip.SetClipboardData(win32con.CF_MAX, str(cliplist))
```

or, using an alternate syntax, you can also construct the list like this:

```
cliplist = [str(MATNR[0]) for MATNR in errorMATNR]
```

And as always, take a look at the docs of the module [here](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32clipboard.html), you might find something helpful

Comment: You mean that, I need to convert the whole list to String by using `str()` ? But how can list convert to a String? It is hard to imagine......

Comment: I assumed that is what you wanted to achive, and actually it is really easy! List to string conversion is done automatically by python if the __str__() method is implemented by the objects that your list contains. In the example, we construct the list of strings, so it's rather trivial to convert them to a list. Of course you can try to copy the list itself by leaving out the str() call.

Comment: It really works! I really need to read the docs you offered in your answer. Thanks a lot~

Comment: No problem! Just make sure to accept the answer so others can find a solution to their problems if they are similar to this one more easily :)